# Angular function modification to modified multiple object keys instead of a single one

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to modify some code so that I can modify multiple values instead of the current single value.

Here is the current code:

```
data = {
    name: 'somename',
    keyOne: 'keyOneValue',
    keyTwo: 'keyTwoValue'
  };


setData(data) {
    this.subject.next(data);
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
}

changeData(key, value) {
    this.data[key] = value;
    this.dataService.setData(this.data);
}
```

Current Usage:

```
changeData('keyOne', 'keyOneValue');
```

How can I update multiple at a time, for example:

`changeData({name: 'someOtherName', keyOne: 'newKeyOneValue'});` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which copies all properties from one source object to a target object.

```
changeData(obj) {
this.data = Object.assign(this.data, obj);
this.dataService.setData(this.data);
}
```